# Wording a question that might have one or more answers

Tags: grammaticality, multiplicity

I have a multiple choice question that might have only one answer or all of the above might be correct. Since I'm teaching kids I want to avoid wordiness, below are my two attempts:

> What is the difference or are the differences between a base 10
>   counting system and a base 16 counting system?

or...

> What is/are the differences between a base 10
>    counting system and a base 16 counting system?

Does anyone have a better approach to this? I feel there must be!

Comment: FWIW, I think you can get away with "What is the difference..." because although there may be many differences, they could all be considered a piece of the whole difference between. So, a reply could look like, "The difference between A and B is that 1) A is... and B is not. 2) B has.... and A does not. Again this is based solely on opinion...

Comment: There's no reason to try to reduce the amount of words you use for a multiple choice question. Don't use unnecessary words; but words used to make the question clearer are not unnecessary. You should use as many words as it takes to make it completely clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the Base 10 counting system different than Base 16?

Comment: I'd say 'How does the Base 10 counting system differ from Base 16?', but this seems like the best method to me.

Answer (score 1):

Explain the difference(s) between a base 10 and a base 16 counting system.